# How to change user agent in iMacros

Tags: imacros

I would like to capture iphone screenshots from firefox using iMacros plugin. The user agent doesn't seems to be triggering.

```
window.resizeTo(720,1280);
var mobile_title_screen_screenshot = 'SET !USERAGENT "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A366 Safari/600.1.4"'+"\n";
mobile_title_screen_screenshot += "SAVEAS TYPE=PNG FOLDER=mobile FILE=mobile-screenshot.png";
iimPlayCode(mobile_title_screen_screenshot)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `REFRESH` after specifying user agent did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure, however you can try to trigger 'Responsive Design View':

```
var mobile_title_screen_screenshot = 'SET !USERAGENT "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A366 Safari/600.1.4"'+"\n";
mobile_title_screen_screenshot += 'EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=* CHAR="m" MODIFIERS="ctrl,shift"'+"\n";
mobile_title_screen_screenshot += "WAIT SECONDS=1"+"\n";
mobile_title_screen_screenshot += "SAVEAS TYPE=PNG FOLDER=mobile FILE=mobile-screenshot.png";
iimPlayCode(mobile_title_screen_screenshot);
```